# Inline M/S manipulation with Voxengo MSED

Tags: ms, mid-side, decoder

I have always heard, and agreed that it is best not to decode the M/S while recording to be able to do it properly in post. This extra step can be a bit time consuming just to be able to monitor for the good takes. I often don't even edit my files but give them away as is, which means I don't want to add an extra layer of complications to their process (unless they want).

A while back I found this awesome M/S plugin by Voxengo called [MSED](http://www.voxengo.com/product/msed/), which has an inline decoder so that I can balance my mid and side even if it has already been decoded. I haven't noticed any decrease in quality. Have you?

Is this a 100% as good as decoding it from scratch in post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that as long as you havent done any other processing to an MS recording you can encode/decode MS as many times as you like without any change in quality at all.

Voxengo plugins are great, I use the free MSED & Recorder a lot!

Comment: Done then! This is officially part of my workflow. Thanks.